# get oauth token with tumblrs official php client

Tags: php, api, oauth, client, tumblr

This is my first time playing with an api and oauth and tumblr has a [php client](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php). I have downloaded and installed the client with composer. This is the code they have to set up the client.

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);
```

I know the consumer key and secret but how do I get the token and token secret with tumblrs php client?

I also know the process of oauth but I don't know how to actually implement it :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so we're in the same page, you can get the user's token and secret by going through the browser sign-in flow dance. Tumblr's flow is pretty much the same as Twitter's so you can use this as reference: [Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). You can look at the **OAuth** part in Tumblr's [Authentication documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth) to get the correct endpoints.

Note that [Tumblr's PHP client](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php) that you linked to has the *default base url* set to `"http://api.tumblr.com/"` whereas the OAuth endpoints (e.g. `request_token`) use `"http://www.tumblr.com"`. To be able to use the OAuth endpoints, you will just have to change the base url. Here's an example of the first step in the sign-in flow, getting a request token:

```
// Requesting for http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
// Change the base url
$client->getRequestHandler()->setBaseUrl('http://www.tumblr.com/');
$req = $client->getRequestHandler()->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', [
  'oauth_callback' => '...',
]);
// Get the result
$result = $req->body->__toString();
```

You should get this in `$result`:

```
oauth_token=ulE1EuaZvJSN0qIKfQO5EFgcrxrOLJF0Cnm7VbLQqj66oF9nwt&oauth_token_secret=PLjC7s4JeIlgm53q7FKL1wqQkFoL0775JC6UkHKiepAQ6TxXxp&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

See this [commit](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/commit/9647a91317f8f7b276be9a9b4e43033236bfb740) in Github for more info on how this was made possible.

Comment: after i get oauth key I cant run any of the api commands like `$client->getBlogInfo($blogname);`. it throws `Fatal error: Uncaught Tumblr\API\RequestException: [404]: Not Found thrown in lib\Tumblr\API\Client.php on line 426` what else am i missing?

Comment: @yamikoWebs Since you've changed the `baseUrl`, you'll have to change it back: `$client->getRequestHandler()->setBaseUrl('http://api.tumblr.com');` or you could create a separate `Tumblr\API\Client` instance.

Comment: its beyond the scope of this question but how do I authorize so I can submit post with the api?

Comment: @yamikoWebs See Step 2 [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). You'll have to pass the `oauth_token` you got from the `oauth/request_token` endpoint and open the authorize page in a browser. Once you complete the sign-in flow, you'll be redirected to the `oauth_callback` where you should then convert the request token into an **access token** (the one you'll be using for API requests).