# How do I get the access_token from tumblr's official php client?

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

I've followed the directions posted in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176109/get-oauth-token-with-tumblrs-official-php-client), but I am stuck.

I am using tumblr/tumblr.php from Github (the official "PHP client for the tumblr API").

I am also following directions [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) (which are actually for twitter), but those directions aren't tailored for the git library I am using.

I have a valid consumer key and secret.

From those I make a request and get oauth_token and oauth_token_secret like so:

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey,$consumerSecret);
$client->getRequestHandler()->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');
$req = $client->getRequestHandler()->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', [
  'oauth_callback' => '...',
]);
// Get the result
$result = $req->body->__toString();
print_r( $result );
```

Which gives me:

```
oauth_token=2C6f...MqSF&oauth_token_secret=HaGh...IJLi&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

Then I send the user to the http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=2C6f...MqSF, so they can allow access for the app. This redirects to: `...?oauth_token=2C6f...MqSF&oauth_verifier=nvjl...GtEa#_=_`

And now in the final step I believe I am supposed to convert my request token to an access token. Is that right? I am doing something wrong:

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey,$consumerSecret);
$client->getRequestHandler()->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');
$req = $client->getRequestHandler()->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', [
  'oauth_token' => '2C6f...MqSF',
  'oauth_verifier' => 'nvjl...GtEa'
]);
// Get the result
$result = $req->body->__toString();
print_r( $result );
```

because I get responses like this one:

```
oauth_signature [AqbbYs0XSZ7plqB0V3UQ6O6SCVI=] does not match expected value [0XwhYMWswlRWgcr6WeA7/RrwrhA=]
```

---

**What is wrong with my last step?**

I am not sure if I should even be sending `oauth_verifier` with the request. Is `#_=_` supposed to be part of `oauth_verifier`? I wouldn't think so. I get signature errors for all the variations Ive tried.

Without the token and tokenSecret I can't make certain calls to the API. I get unauthorized 403 responses. Same when I use the token and token_secret from the second step. I'm pretty sure I need a new token/secret pair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just are passing the oauth_token incorrectly in the last step, and skipping out on oauth_token_secret altogeter.

I've compiled this working code (which you can also now find posted on the Wiki at https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/wiki/Authentication):

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// some variables that will be pretttty useful
$consumerKey = '<your consumer key>';
$consumerSecret = 'your consumer secret>';
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
$requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

// start the old gal up
$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', array());

// get the oauth_token
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

// tell the user where to go
echo 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $data['oauth_token'];
$client->setToken($data['oauth_token'], $data['oauth_token_secret']);

// get the verifier
echo "\noauth_verifier: ";
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$line = fgets($handle);

// exchange the verifier for the keys
$verifier = trim($line);
$resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $verifier));
$out = $result = $resp->body;
$data = array();
parse_str($out, $data);

// and print out our new keys
$token = $data['oauth_token'];
$secret = $data['oauth_token_secret'];
echo "\ntoken: " . $token . "\nsecret: " . $secret;

// and prove we're in the money
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);
$info = $client->getUserInfo();
echo "\ncongrats " . $info->user->name . "!\n";
```

Comment: Where do you get vendor/autoload.php? There is no such file in the Tumblr API.