# OAuth - getAccessToken Tumblr

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

This is My code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_GET['oauth_verifier'] && $_GET['oauth_token'])
{
    $oauth = new OAuth(
        'wvo35DiIDRY5SMfA47OpDDDW958yWckPcs00gFwQdaGtk7e###',
        'LvX6zPEtNxZU4sO3BO0V7kkVxI7V0TB6CnSXfIFRKVUdTyQ###',
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'],
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']
    );
    $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $accesToken = $oauth->getAccessToken('http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token'); // ERROR LINE

    $oauth->setToken($accessToken["oauth_token"],$accessToken["oauth_token_secret"]);
    exit();
}

$oauth = new OAuth(
    'wvo35DiIDRY5SMfA47OpDDDW958yWckPcs00gFwQdaGtk7e###',
    'LvX6zPEtNxZU4sO3BO0V7kkVxI7V0TB6CnSXfIFRKVUdTyQ###',
    OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,
    OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI
);

$requestToken = $oauth->getRequestToken('http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

header("Location: https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={$requestToken['oauth_token']}");
```

And i have error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid
>   auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in

How can I fix this?

Comment: check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235182/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-tumblrs-official-php-client] it can help you

Comment: Thanks, but i don't use API Tumblr, i use this lib: [Github jaapz Tumblr](https://github.com/jaapz/Tumblr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey.. I checked everything, and varibles:

- $_SESSION['oauth_token']
- $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']

was empty.. because I made a mistake in varibles name:

```
$requestToken = $oauth->getRequestToken('http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token');

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

At the beginning i use $requestToken, but next i use $request_token.

Thanks and sorry!